# Уникальное значение массива

Tags: javascript

Есть массив. Например [1,2,4,5,3,5,2,1,3] . Как вывести его уникальное значение.
В данном случае [1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [1,2,4,5,3,5,2,1,3];
let uniqArr = arr.filter((val, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(val) === i);
console.log(uniqArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Тоже очень простое решение:

```js
   var arr1 = [1,2,4,5,3,5,2,1,3];
    let set = new Set(arr1);
    let res = Array.from(set);
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

выбирайте решение которое нравится

```js
function unique(arr) {
  var obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var str = arr[i];
    obj[str] = true;
  }

  return Object.keys(obj);
}

var arr1 = [1,2,4,5,3,5,2,1,3];

console.log(unique(arr1));
```

lodash.js

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,4,5,3,5,2,1,3];
console.log(_.uniq(arr1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```